# How do I get my music off my iPod 4th generation 2004

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, iphone, ipod, ipod-classic

I have a 4th generation ipod from 2004 and have wonderful playlists and music that I want to get onto my 2015 MacBook and in turn onto my iPhone.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [iMazing](http://imazing.com/). Used it before to copy old photos from an iPad and it worked great!

Answer (score 1):

Use iFunbox or try iExplorer to attempt to get all data off of the device. It will have encrypted file names, but the metadata will remain.

In other words, in iFunbox, find the iTunes_Control folder in the root file system, then right click music and click copy to my computer.

In iExplorer, go into music, then press <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> (paste it in the desired directory after). If you are on Mac, go to music then press <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>. (Paste it in the desired directory after.)